# Using EntityCommand to call stored procedures but result is always empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using entity framework and azure for db. The fact is EF is not working fine with stored procedures when they are not returning fields from models. The auto generated code in model.Context.cs file returns integer.

```
       public virtual int GetLogTransaction(Nullable<long> transactionId)
    {
        var transactionIdParameter = transactionId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("transactionId", transactionId) :
            new ObjectParameter("transactionId", typeof(long));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("IHUBEntities.GetLogTransaction", transactionIdParameter);
    }
```

So I decide to avoid this file and using EntityCommand to connect to db and execute my procedure.

```
      EntityConnection sqlConnection = new EntityConnection("name=IHUBEntities");
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using ( EntityCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {

            LogTransactionInfor lgInfor = new LogTransactionInfor();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "IHUBEntities.GetLogTransaction";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                EntityParameter param = new EntityParameter();
                param.Value = transactionId;
                param.ParameterName = "transactionId";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                      //get reader content here
                    }

                }
                cmd.Connection.Close();

            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lgInfor.err = ex.StackTrace;
                Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            return lgInfor;
        }
```

The problem is the reader is always empty, give me zero results. However, when I using the same input parameter to test on db sql, it will return desired result.
So, I think the problem is may because from the way I wrote the procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLogTransaction]
@transactionId bigint = 0
 AS
 DECLARE
@tablename nvarchar(261),

@obj_name nvarchar(4000),
@pk bigint,
@pk_name nvarchar(500),
@opt nvarchar(20),
@usrId bigint,
@usrName nvarchar(200),
@sql nvarchar(4000),
@cn int
  DECLARE
@userTable table(
    usrId bigint,
    usrName nvarchar(200)
)
  BEGIN

 //select from different tables and set values to parameters
 ......

  select  @obj_name as obj_name, @pk as pk, @pk_name as pk_name, @opt as opt, @usrId as usrId, @usrName as usrName
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you're using 'Database First'.

Have you set the return type of the stored procedure properly?

Sorry, I'm a bit new, so I'm not sure how to upload images, but:
1) Open your .EDMX file
2) In the model browser, find 'Function Imports'
3) Double click on your stored procedure.
4) Click 'Get Column Information'.
5) Click 'Update'.
6) Done!

If the stored procedure doesn't appear in 'Function Imports' you need to update your model from the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works. I am totally new to entity framework and this problem drives me mad for several days.